# How to give credit to others' work

Tags: protocol

I am totally new to Ubuntu, but might start to fiddle around with open source software and make some modifications at some point in the next few months. If I were to do that, what protocol would I need to follow e.g how would I give credit to the person/s who created that piece of software - that I decide to modify, where would I give the credit, and what would the appropriate format and structure of the acknowledgement be?

Any help or advice that anyone out there can provide me would be much appreciated.

Yours Sincerely,

Alaister

Comment: This question is not related to Ubuntu at all but rather a license question. It depends for each software you manipulate on the individual license

Answer (score 0):

If you're not "forking" the project - distributing your own, modified version while the original still exists - you don't have to do a thing. This is particularly relevant if you contribute your changes to the original project, in which case they become available to everyone, and it is *they* who must worry about the correct way to give credit to *you* (usually by sticking you in an Authors file somewhere, if your contribution is large, and by leaving your name on the commits in their version control software in any case).

If you *are* distributing modified versions, it's going to depend on the project. Usually, the license under which the software is released will explain all your obligations.